# check number of stopwords in a text column pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How can I check number of stopwords present in a text column pandas. I have a huge dataset so efficient approach is really appreciated.

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords    
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))

print(df)
      text                      
0  stackoverflow is good              
1  stackoverflow is not good
```

This is my desired output?

```
print(df)
      text                      number_of_stopwords
0  stackoverflow is good              1
1  stackoverflow is not good          2
```

I have tried something like below but not working.

```
df.str.split().apply(lambda x: len(x in stop_words))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use intersection of sets:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords    
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))

df['n'] = df['text'].str.split().apply(lambda x: len(set(x) & stop_words))
```

Or:

```
df['n'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: len(set(x.split()) & stop_words))
```

---

```
print (df)
                        text  n
0      stackoverflow is good  1
1  stackoverflow is not good  2
```

Comment: @user214 - Is converted list in lambda function to set?

Comment: How can I also get count of words that are not in stop_words?

Comment: You need `df['not'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: len([i for i in x.split() if i not in stop_words]))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use LC,

```
df['number_of_stopwords'] = df.text.apply(lambda x: len([i for i in x.split() if i in stop_words]))

df['not_in_stopwords'] = df.text.apply(lambda x: len([i for i in x.split() if I not in stop_words]))
```

It fares well in terms of performance,

```
df = df.append([df]*1000000,ignore_index=True)

%timeit df.text.apply(lambda x: len([i for i in x.split() if i in stop_words]))
2.27 s ± 33 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit df['text'].str.split().apply(lambda x: len(set(x) & stop_words))
3.29 s ± 131 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```